# Netbeans error after restart laptop and netbeans

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, netbeans7.0

I've met an error after i restarted my netbeans and my laptop. Before the restart everything was working fine. Anyone know how can I solve the error?

Here's the Glassfish log:

```
[#|2011-08-11T00:50:04.436+0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=60;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Cannot start container  security
java.lang.RuntimeException: JACC Policy provider: repository not initialized
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyConfigurationFactoryImpl.getContextDirectoryName(PolicyConfigurationFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyConfigurationFactoryImpl.getPolicyConfigurationImplFromDirectory(PolicyConfigurationFactoryImpl.java:222)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyConfigurationFactoryImpl.inService(PolicyConfigurationFactoryImpl.java:210)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.web.integration.WebSecurityManager.loadPolicyConfiguration(WebSecurityManager.java:295)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.web.integration.WebSecurityManager.initialise(WebSecurityManager.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.web.integration.WebSecurityManager.<init>(WebSecurityManager.java:169)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.web.integration.WebSecurityManagerFactory.createManager(WebSecurityManagerFactory.java:293)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityContainer.generatePolicy(SecurityContainer.java:120)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityContainer.postConstruct(SecurityContainer.java:103)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineInfo.getContainer(EngineInfo.java:93)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.startContainers(ApplicationLifecycle.java:955)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:870)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2011-08-11T00:50:04.452+0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=60;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Aborting, Failed to start container com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityContainer|#]

[#|2011-08-11T00:50:04.452+0800|WARNING|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=60;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Error occurred
java.lang.Exception: Aborting, Failed to start container com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityContainer
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:870)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2011-08-11T00:50:04.483+0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=60;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer prepare method|#]

[#|2011-08-11T00:50:04.499+0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=60;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while preparing the app|#]

[#|2011-08-11T00:50:04.499+0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=60;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Aborting, Failed to start container com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityContainer
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Aborting, Failed to start container com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityContainer
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:870)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Aborting, Failed to start container com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityContainer
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:138)
    ... 29 more
|#]

[#|2011-08-11T00:50:04.530+0800|SEVERE|glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=60;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Exception while preparing the app : Aborting, Failed to start container com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityContainer
java.lang.Exception: Aborting, Failed to start container com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityContainer
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:282)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:141)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:870)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:410)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1067)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1247)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:222)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:234)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your glassfish is having problems starting up. I would suggest you try the following:

1.) Remove any copies of your app from glassfish ( you may have had a bad deploy)

2.) Clear the glassfish cache

3.) Reinstall glassfish

Comment: what does removing copies of my app from glassfish? my apps are in netbeans, or do you mean my jdbc resources, etc, in glassfish?

Comment: Your sources are in your netbeans project folder. However when you deploy to glassfish copies are placed in the glassfish directory. The error message says that glassfish cannot start the parts of its container. This is likely either due to a leftover somewhere in the glassfish deployment directory or due to a corrupted element in the glassfish pieces. If you have manually placed items in the glassfish classpath for example they could have been corrupted on restart.

Comment: Oh I see. I have reinstalled glassfish instead, and will be setting up my JDBC resource pools in my admin console, hope everything goes fine after that. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
Reinstalling Glassfish is not a good option. The correct answer is to clear all applications and all cache data from Glassfish domain.
Following https://gist.github.com/agritsik/7e17cb876553b13ad6d1e6dcd6aa131b

I cleared the following folders:

- $GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/*
- $GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/osgi-cache/*
- $GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/*